# Question about the need of ADC and DAC converter

Tags: dac

why we want to convert digital signal to analog signal back into digital? between electronics device, why would we want to do that? Is there any advantage of transmitting analog signal through a cable between electronic devices?

Comment: Usually it's the other way. We have an analog signal (like a sound, for example). We convert it to digital and do something with it (store it on disk and then retrieve it again later, maybe, or email it to our friends). Then we convert it back to analog (so we can listen to it).

Comment: Here's a somewhat realistic example with a lot of conversions: audio from your phone (stored digitally) is converted to an analog signal and passed (via the headphone jack) to your car's stereo (aux jack). In the stereo, it might be converted to digital for signal processing and class-D amplification, after which it is filtered again to produce analog audio that drives the speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Sending analog signals over connecting lines is worse than sending digital signals (in most cases).

The reason: analog line is sensitive to very small interference, while (properly designed) digital line ignores interference until the latest reaches huge levels.

Comment: How does this answer work when an amplifier is driving a loudspeaker connected by wires?

Comment: I am working in a laboratory where we convert digital into analog and again back to digital between two lab electronic devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are all sorts of cases where sending analog signals are preferable to digital ones.  I am thinking of primarily RF communications, high speed serial, and coherent optical.  And all for similar reasons - namely limited bandwidth and crappy channels (intersymbol interference, multipath, crosstalk, high frequency attenuation, etc).

Modern digital RF communications systems (WiFi, LTE, etc.) use high order modulations including QPSK, QAM, and OFDM.  QAM involves changing both the amplitude and phase of the carrier signal.  This is usually done with a component called an IQ modulator, and the I and Q inputs are driven by high speed DACs.  At the receive side, the I and Q signals would be extracted and sent to high speed ADCs.  Then digital signal processing is used to compensate for carrier offsets and what not and recover the transmitted data.  For more complex modulation like OFDM, an FFT operation is required to modulate and demodulate signals on the orthogonal carriers, and this operation is performed digitally before the signal is sent through DACs to an IQ modulator.

For high speed serial communications (around 50 Gbps and up) we're starting to see things like PAM-4 used to get the symbol rate down.  In this case, DACs are used to generate the transmit signal with digitally generated pre-emphasis to compensate for high frequency loss.  At the receive side, ADCs are used to bring the signal back into the digital domain where equalization is performed digitally to reduce intersymbol interference.

Even slower-speed serial communications use ADCs and DACs.  Take gigabit ethernet for example.  Gigabit ethernet transmits with PAM-5 encoding and does local echo cancellation with a combination of analog techniques and digital signal processing.

Coherent optical communications are the same beast as RF, just with a lot more bandwidth (~100 GSa/sec ADCs and DACs).  High order modulation (QAM), OFDM, etc. are all being looked at for long range, spectrally efficient data transmission.

Comment: You're confusing digital with binary here. Network communications you're talking about are strictly digital. On the other hand, all electrical signals (including binary) are analog by nature.

Answer (score 1):

Conversions Digital to Analog then back to Digital are typical for legacy systems. Before digital electronics developed enough processing power and became cheap enough, many analog consumer interfaces were standardized and widely adopted. Examples include analog [audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) and [video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video#Analog_video) interfaces.

Modern audio and video devices are commonly digital, but many still support legacy analog interfaces for compatibility reasons. There is no real advantage here (you'd use modern digital interfaces for best performance) other than interoperability with older devices you already have.